# If I press the FN key my keyboard gets totally stucked

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I bought a new keyboard (a PAWHITS RGB Backlit Gaming Keyboard and Mouse Combo USB Wired Membrane Keyboard )

And I wanted to change the color pressing FN + 5. But the weird thing is that everytime I press FN the keyboard locks and I can't press anything unless I press FN again. Another weird thing is that if I press FN it automatically full screens the window in chrome, as if I was pressing F11

Edit: If I press FN+F12 it opens the calculator just fine but nothing else from the FN buttons seems to work. The keyboard comes new

I used sharpkeys and as I suspected, if I press Fn it says I pressed F11.
So I disabled F11 to see if that stops the keyboard locking but it does not [Here's a photo of my sharpkeys "config"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbQxo.png)